# SmartSheet API triggered when adding row

Tags: node.js, smartsheet-api

I've created a node.js script that collects all rows in my SmartSheet and then updates the rows that meet a certain criteria. It works fine.

However, rather than having a script that continuously collects all rows and checks for the desired criteria, I would prefer to have the script only check for new rows that are added and then update certain cell values for only those new rows at the time they are added. Is there a way to update only new rows immediately after they're added via the SmartSheet API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes look at their webHook section in the documentation use it to trigger functions when something happen.

Answer (score 0):

According to SmartSheet's API documentation, currently the only events available for subscribing to via Webhook are all events("*.*"). Which means if you create a webhook you'll be subscribing to any changes on a sheet. You'll have to handle  filtering updated rows versus new rows in your code.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).